# How to repartiton hard drive while upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade, license-key

I need to upgrade Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 on a laptop.
The problem is that I want to repartition my hard drive. Currently I have two partitions and I want to combine them. If I just update to win10, it will stay as it is, with all the files.

I can also install it from windows image from bootable usb and reformat my hard drive there. Although I don't know which license code to use for installation then. I tried entering the code from System Info in Windows 10 fresh installation, but it rejected it

Can I look up the licence code in the system info and use it to reinstall Windows 8.1 fresh and then upgrade? Or what's the optimal solution?

Comment: Perform the upgrade then reparation your HDD.  Once you upgrade Windows 10 will automatically activate if asked for a key just hit "skip"

Comment: @Ramhound so install update to win10 from windows update centre and then partition? Can I even do that with OS installed?

Comment: Yes you can do it with OS already installed. It will recognize your computer from when you did the upgrade. See [How to Clean Install Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/224342/how-to-clean-install-windows-10/).

Comment: @akalikin Please read me full comment I already addressed your follow up question